# Jquery Multiselect to MVC4 Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, multi-select

I am trying to recieve the selected values of my multi-select box. Through Ajax call.

Below is my test action

```
public ActionResult MultiSelect(String[] test)
{
    String[] arrayornot = test; //null being recieved. or the string if hardcoded
}
```

the Jquery

```
    alert($('#county').val()); // London, Brim
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MultiSelect", "APITest")',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: { test: $('#county').val()},
        success: function (result) {
            $('#myDiv').html(result);
        }
    });
```

if I hardcode it to a string, it works fine. with `String[]` or `String` endpoint. If it passes in a comma seperated string, i can sort it on server side. or a string array is better.

Comment: Having got the idea to convert the array to string, comma seperated in Jquery, its literally just `$('#county').val().toString()` . Still unsure how to pass it as an array though.

Comment: Have you tried removing the object notation for the data? When trying to resolve the parameter, it won't be looking for an object with a property named test - it will be looking for an array of strings.

Comment: Try adding the selected items into a JS arraylist and then pass it as a JSON string

Comment: @anthr When I print it, i get `London, Brim` So I am unsure what object notation it even has. Or how to map this to a String array.

Comment: @Murali Thanks, but the reason Id prefer it to recognise as an array, is so that I dont have to change lots of code to accept strings. Id rather not have to deserialise it on server side. It seems similar to sending a normal comma delimited string either way. Unless a JSON string would map to a String Array?

Comment: Please check my answer. It will map JSON array to `String[]` in server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue you were having. I found the answer in the following link.

http://dovetailsoftware.com/clarify/kmiller/2010/02/24/jquery-1-4-breaks-asp-net-mvc-actions-with-array-parameters

Basically what you need to do is to add the following line and the values will pass as an array.

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

Answer (score 2):

The error is the $Ajax configuration set the method traditional: true then your problem is solved.

var selectedItems=$('#county').val();

```
$.ajax({

    url: '@Url.Action("MultiSelect", "APITest")',

    type: 'POST',

    cache: false,

    traditional: true, 

    data: { test: JSON.stringify(selectedItems)},

    success: function (result) {
        $('#myDiv').html(result);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use javascript array and convert into JSON string

```
var selectedItems=$('#county').val(); // returns the array of selected items
```

Then use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MultiSelect", "APITest")',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: { test: JSON.stringify(selectedItems)},
        success: function (result) {
            $('#myDiv').html(result);
        }
    });
```

JSON.Stringify is not available in IE 7. Please use [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I must ask, what is the difference between SelectedItems, and SelectedArray.i thought the items was an array :S Maybe thats where I went wrong.

Comment: @Doomsknight, Thats perfect :) I changed my answer. Split also returns array :)

Comment: I am just getting a single element in the array with string value =  `"[\"London\",\"Brim\"]"` (Same as previous code you suggested)

Comment: Still the same, My guess is im missing some flag, to say incoming JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `string[]` (string array) in method parameter. use `string` parameter. and convert this comma separated string in to an array on server side.

use following code,

Server side,

```
    public ActionResult MultiSelect(string test)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

JQuery Code,

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MultiSelect", "OrderCreation")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                data: { test: $('#county').val().toString() },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#myDiv').html(result);
                }
            });
```